# Simple javascript regexp to extract a part starting and ending with a letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get this regexp to return, and only return `"flies a"`

```
s = 'test <!-- flies are little birds --> end';
alert(s.match(/f(.*)a/));
```

Why does this return

```
flies a
lies
```

How can I make the f and a obligatory?

Thank you

Comment: really appreciate your quick comments, thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.match` returns an array. The first element is the whole matched text and each other element is the content of a capture group. You have one capture group, so the second element is the text captured by it.

Either remove the group or just ignore the other elements in the array. You have to access the first one in any case:

```
var match = s.match(/f(.*)a/)[0]; // or /f.*a/
```

---

P.S.: `alert` is a bad debugging tool, use `console.log` or `console.dir` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put in the brackets.

```
alert(s.match(/f.*a/));
```

The brackets create a capture group, which lets you specify that you're interested in particular parts of the match. In this case you're interested in the entire thing so you don't need any brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove parentheses or place the whole expression into additional parentheses:

`s.match(/f.*a/)[0];`
or
`s.match(/(f(.*)a)/)[1];`